# Is there any way to find port number in HttpsUrlConnection?

Tags: java, networking

I created one app which will download data from a remote server. I used ***HttpsUrlConnection*** Class to perform this. Data is getting downloaded successfully. But I want to know ,through which port the communication is happening (***Both my machine's port number and remote machine's port number***) . Can anyone please help me to find out the port number? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

As far as the remote host's port number goes that is whatever you specify as the port in your url. If that is not available for any reason you can get it by getting a URL object from the connection and then get the port from the URL object:

```
int port = connection.getURL().getPort();
```

When it comes to which port your local machine is using for the connection I am not sure java supports that. You can list active connections in many operating systems using `netstat`. Syntax may vary depending on operating system ([Unix](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?netstat%208), [Windows](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/netstat.mspx)).

Comment: connection.getURL().getPort() returning -1 , because I didn't mention any port number in URL. But by assumption I can say HTTPS will use its default port 443. Is it possible to prove it?

Comment: Interesting, didn't know it would return -1. If you have not supplied a port, default for https is 443. Java wouldn't magically change this to another port, so I don't think you need much proof unless you have a special requirement for it. Where would you need to prove it? In Java code or elsewhere?

Comment: I need to get the port number and I've to use it in my java code. We can say that HTTPS communication happens at port 443. But is there any way to get it by using any methods in java?

Comment: According to the javadoc getPort returns "the port number, or -1 if the port is not set". This means it should return the correct port number if you have set a port number explicitly. If you have not set it, you are using the default port which is 443. So whenever you are getting back a -1 value for a https connection the port the connection is using is 443.

Comment: You may also want to have a look at getDefaultPort() in URL: "Gets the default port number of the protocol associated with this URL."